# I can't figure out why I am getting the following error "Error: Element type is invalid:"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am pretty new to React and even newer to Firebase. I am following a tutorial from Robin Wieruch on using React with Firebase. Clearly, there is something that I have done wrong but it eludes me. I am using a pattern of using folders to name my components with an index.js file in each Component folder to hold the code.

Here is the index.js for the App Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes'

import Navigation from '../Navigation'
import LandingPage from '../Landing'
import SignUpPage from '../SignUp'
import SignInPage from '../SignIn'
import PasswordForgetPage from '../PasswordForget'
import HomePage from '../Home'
import AccountPage from '../Account'
import AdminPage from '../Admin'

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Navigation />

    <hr />

    <Route exact path={ROUTES.LANDING} component={LandingPage} />
    <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} component={SignUpPage} />
    <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} component={SignInPage} />
    <Route path={ROUTES.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={PasswordForgetPage} />
    <Route path={ROUTES.HOME} component={HomePage} />
    <Route path={ROUTES.ACCOUNT} component={AccountPage} />
    <Route path={ROUTES.ADMIN} component={AdminPage} />
  </Router>
)

export default App
```

Here is the index.js file for the SignUp Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { compose } from 'recompose'

import FirebaseContext, { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes'

const SignUpPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>SignUp</h1>
    <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
      { firebase => <SignUpForm firebase={firebase} />}
    </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
  </div>
)

...

export default SignUpPage

export { SignUpForm, SignUpLink }
```

I'm not sure if any other files would be helpful.

I apologize. It seems I forgot the most important file. Here is index.js from the src folder:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import './index.css'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'

import App from './components/App'
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/Firebase'

ReactDOM.render(
    // make Firebase Context available to the app
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={ new Firebase() }>
      <App />
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root'),
  )
```

The error appears to be at line 12 of this file ReactDOM.render.

Per request from @Victor, here are the Firebase components:

index.js from Firebase folder

```
import FirebaseContext, { withFirebase } from './context'
import Firebase from './firebase'

export default Firebase

export { FirebaseContext, withFirebase }
```

context.js from the Firebase folder

```
import React from 'react'

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null)

// create the HOC withFirebase
export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    { firebase => <Component { ...props } firebase={ firebase } />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
)

export default FirebaseContext
```

firebase.js from the Firebase folder

```
import app from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
// import 'firebase/database'

// the constant value when the environment = 'production'
const prodConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_SENDER_ID,
}

// the constant value when the environment !== 'production'
const devConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_SENDER_ID,
}

// set the config constant to the appropriate value
const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? prodConfig : devConfig

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    // initialize the app with the Firebase config
    app.initializeApp(config)

    this.auth = app.auth()
  }

  // ***** Auth API ***** (use the offical Firebase endpoint)
  doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = ( email, password ) => this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )

  // ***** SignIn ***** (use the offical Firebase endpoint)
  doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = ( email, password ) => this.auth.SignInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )

  // ***** SignIn ***** (use the offical Firebase endpoint)
  doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = ( email, password ) => this.auth.SignInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )

  // ***** SignOut ***** (use the offical Firebase endpoint)
  doSignOut = ( email, password ) => this.auth.SignOut()

  // ***** Password Reset ***** (use the offical Firebase endpoint)
  doPasswordReset = email => this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail( email )

  // ***** Password Update ***** (use the offical Firebase endpoint)
  doPasswordUpdate = password => this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword( password )
}

export default Firebase
```

Hope that does it.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? Which line ?

Comment: Your error is not reproducible. Please provide the full output of the error or just the line where it occurred.

Comment: @AtinSingh I apologize I forgot to add the file in which I got the error (brain fart). I have edited the original post and added index.js from the src folder. the error occurs at the ReactDom.render.

Comment: @JosmyFaure see the comment above.

Comment: How does the `./components/Firebase` file look?

Comment: Swinging from way back - could you maybe need to have your value written like value="'" + new Firebase() + "'". Obviously speaking with no understanding of this particular issue, but in other instances I have had to write out in a similar fashion to this. Maybe you will know the way to do it in this instance having this little snippet reminding you?

Comment: @VictorF I added the firebase files to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I figured it out. The problem was that I was trying to expose FirebaseContext.Consumer in two places, in the context.js file within the Firebase folder (which is where in belongs in this app). But I had left the code exposing FirebaseContext.Consumer in the SignUpPage block in the index.js file within the SignUp folder as well (which is where I originally placed it -- before I built the HOC (context.js). After looking at it (but not really seeing it) for a day and a half, it dawned on me that I was trying to pull double duty. The solution was to refactor SignUpPage as follows (compare with my original post above):

index.js for the SignUp Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { compose } from 'recompose'

import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes'

const SignUpPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>SignUp Page</h1>
    <SignUpForm />
  </div>
)

...

const SignUpForm = compose(withRouter, withFirebase,)(SignUpFormBase)

export default SignUpPage

export { SignUpForm, SignUpLink }
```

Thanks to all you contributors to my thought process.